# Exploding pandas dataframe by list to multiple rows with a new column for multiindex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a Pandas dataframe where the columns are 'month' and 'year', and a 'value_list' which is a list of values - one for each day of the month. Something like this -

| year | month | value_list |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1990 | 2 | [10, 20, 30, 40, ...... 290, 300] |
| 1990 | 3 | [110, 120, 130, 140, ...... 390, 400] |

I want to unpack these into multiple rows - one for each day (new column), so that I get something like the following -

| year | month | day | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1990 | 2 | 1 | 10 |
| 1990 | 2 | 2 | 20 |
| 1990 | 2 | 3 | 30 |
| 1990 | 2 | 4 | 40 |

and so on.

I tried using `df.explode()` but to no avail since the index gets reset or is set to a new single index. How can I automatically get the dates (essentially creating a year, month, date multiindex) while unpacking the lists?

Comment: `df.explode('value_list')` should work if `df['value_list']` is a true list. If not working, try `df['value_list']=df['value_list'].str.strip('[]').str.split(',')` followed by `df.explode('value_list')`

Comment: Apologies if I wasn't very clear. df.explode does help with exploding/unpacking, but the second part where all the exploded rows have a different value in a new column (day) is what I am unable to get. What I have is a true list, but I see your point - thank you!

Comment: Ok, fine you clarified and there is a solution already. Keep coding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you [**`explode`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html), you can create the `day` sequences using [**`groupby-transform`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with `cumcount`:

```py
df = df.explode('value_list').rename(columns={'value_list': 'value'})
df['day'] = df.groupby(['year', 'month']).transform('cumcount').add(1)

#    year  month value  day
# 0  1990      2    10    1
# 0  1990      2    20    2
# 0  1990      2    30    3
# 0  1990      2    40    4
# 0  1990      2   290    5
# 0  1990      2   300    6
# 1  1990      3   110    1
# 1  1990      3   120    2
# 1  1990      3   130    3
# 1  1990      3   140    4
# 1  1990      3   390    5
# 1  1990      3   400    6
```

---

Also as @wwnde commented, if `value_list` doesn't contain true lists but just strings that look like lists, convert them to lists before exploding:

```py
df.value_list = df.value_list.str.strip('[]').str.split(r'\s*,\s*')
```